# scrollview doesn't scroll setting height programmatically

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I would start with my goal. What I want to achieve is to have layout which is 3 times bigger then real screen of phone.

Right now I try to test my solution, but I have problem with scrolling.
This is how look my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        tools:context=".Zo"
        android:id="@+id/zo_root"
>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        ></FrameLayout >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/Yellow"
        ></FrameLayout >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        ></FrameLayout >
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My code behind:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zo);
        setParameterForScroolView();   
    }

    private void setParameterForScroolView()
    {
        ParameterKeeper parameterKeeper = new ParameterKeeper(this);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zo_root);
        linearLayout.getLayoutParams().height = parameterKeeper.getHeightOfScreen() *3;       

    }
```

The code behind works well, cause my whole screen is red, but I can't scroll it at all.

There was [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447594/scrollview-dont-scroll) which said, that I need to remove from `scrollView`   `android:fillViewport="true"`. After that my LinearLayout diseapers like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599837/linearlayout-not-expanding-inside-a-scrollview/2606641#comment53044069_2606641) question.

I added LinearLayout as root ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811032/scrollview-not-scrolling-at-all)) but it not helped me at all.

Have you got any idea to solve it?

I try also set `height` `1600dp` instead `400dp` for Root `LinearLayout` in `xml` to be sure, that it's not problem with recalculating `view`. It's not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some way scroll doesn't work if the child elements have layout_weight and I change programmatically value of height in parent's view.

In my case the only way to make it works was to set height equal to size of screen in every of `frame layout` in code of activity. This way I could reach my goal which was to have `layout height == 3 x real screen size`

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the size of the wrong layout. you suppose to modify the height of the first layout inside the scroll view.

Comment: And height for root layout should be set as  match_parent?

Comment: it doesn't work it fit child linear layout to screen even if i set for it huge amount of dp like 2000dp. The only solution was to set height for every layout. I would put solution today, anyway thx for help